# Finding cycle in graph using DFS - recursion problem

Tags: python

I tried to make an aglorithm that searches for cycles in undirected graph but it seems like return statement doesn't work.

```
def wrapped_dfs_recursive(G: Dict[int, List[int]], current_vertex: int, parent: int, visited: List[int] = None):
    
    for neighbour in G[current_vertex]:
        if neighbour in visited and neighbour != parent:
            print("Found cycle")
            return True

    visited.append(current_vertex)

    if current_vertex in G.keys():
        for vertex in G[current_vertex]:
            if vertex not in visited:
                wrapped_dfs_recursive(G, current_vertex=vertex, parent=current_vertex, visited=visited)
    else:
        return None
    return False
```

When I execute this code for a simple, cyclic graph it returns False, but it also prints the message "Found cycle" two times. So if it executes the print function why doesn't it return True? Did I make something wrong with the stop condition?

Comment: Could you give an example input?

Comment: For example `cyclic = {1: [2, 4], 2: [1, 3], 3: [2, 4], 4: [3, 1]}`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the issue. I missed the word 'return' when I was calling wrapped_dfs_recursive(), so it wasn't changing anything and finally returned False.